# Ortools CVRP reuse the used vehicle

Tags: python-3.x, or-tools

I want to use or tools to solve the CVRP problem and I know can use `routing.IsVehicleUsed(assignment, vehicle_id)` method know the vehicle is used or not.

Can I reuse the used vehicle.
Because I have a problem ,when I set `data['num_vehicles'] = 1` or-tools returns no result but when I set `data['num_vehicles'] = 4` I got a solution.

It cannot be modified the data['vehicle_capacities'] so I want to the used vehicle can start again when it return start point

Answer (score 0):

Once a vehicle reach its end node, it's over. End node are always the last node of a vehicle route.

You should create some dummy node (duplicate of depot) to simulate an unload please take a look at the refuel station example in the sample directory on github...